# Share a video with Google circles

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I want to share a private YouTube video via Google Circles.  Eventually I also want to display that video in my website, but it should still only be seen by the "friends" in the Google Circles. So I did the following.  I created two different Gmail accounts.  I created a circle for one of them, and then added the other person (i.e. Gmail account) to that circle.

I uploaded a private video to the first Gmail account, and then, I attempted to share it with the circle.  I did that by typing in the URL in a share box.  Unfortunately, the "person" who appears in my circle cannot view the video - he gets a message that it is "private".  This happens even though he is logged in to the browser via his Gmail account.

So why can't I succeed in sharing one video to all people in a circle?
Thanks

Comment: are you talking about google plus? why do you say gmail? to share a video with a circle, simply paste the link and select the circle. The video cannot be private on YouTube otherwise only you can see it.

Comment: OK, so you are saying that there is NO way to make a private video visible to only a few friends in Google circle and nobody else?  It would have to be private or unlisted, it seems to me, if I don't want the general public to see it.

Comment: I think what luca is saying is that your question is a little unclear on a couple of points. Does the circle contain Google+ accounts or does it just contain an email address? Google treats the two differently - an Account can be reliably shared with, while an email address (even if it is a GMail address) cannot be trusted in the same way. If the account is actually a Google+ account, update the question to make this clear, please.

Comment: This is what I did.  First I created 2 different gmail accounts.  For each gmail account, I created a google circle identity.  Then as Account #1 I uploaded a video and made it private.  Then, for both accounts I created a circle.  In Account #1, I shared the video with all people in its circle (the only actual person in that circle was Account #2).  When I look at Account #2 google+ page, it says that Account #1 has Account #2 in a circle, and also says that Account #2 has another person (who I have not mentioned) in its own circle.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer possible to share video with Google circles.

Refer to [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/20YFYGvJVxI) for more details.